# Show that $| \cot \pi (x+ir) + i| = \dfrac{2}{1+e^{2 \pi r}}$.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, proof-explanation

It's been a while I am trying to prove $| \cot \pi (x+ir) + i| = \dfrac{2}{1+e^{2 \pi r}}$ and as I couldn't suceed I tried [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=abs%28cot%28pi%20%28a%2Bib%29%29%20%2B%20i%29%20-%202%2F%281%2Be%5E%282%20pi%20b%29%29) but it seems that the equality is incorrect (?)

This appears in Section 4.14 of Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function* on the approximation to $\zeta(s)$ in the critical strip.

[image]

PS - Not relevant to the title but I think the claim that the final formula is valid for all values of $s$ is incorrect becasue for negative $\sigma$, $|z|^{-\sigma} < x^{-\sigma}$ is invalid (the last line of the picture).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By wolfram alpha we get [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=i%20-%20%28i%20%28e%5E%28-i%20%CF%80%20z%29%20%2B%20e%5E%28i%20%CF%80%20z%29%29%29%2F%28e%5E%28-i%20%CF%80%20z%29%20-%20e%5E%28i%20%CF%80%20z%29%29&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22%20-%3E%20%7B%22Math%22%7D) so you get $$\cot (\pi z)+i=(2 i e^{2 i π z})/(-1 + e^{2 i π z})=(2 i)/(-e^{-2 i π z} + 1)$$
and since in the book $x$ is half and odd integer this leads to an absolute value of
$$\frac{2}{1+e^{2\pi r}}.$$

Comment: You have the book? :) My bad, I should have write x is half of odd integer I thought it is irrelevant - Q: I think the claim I wrote in PS of OP also incorrect?

Comment: @Ali $\sigma>0$ in 4.11. Yes I have the book :)

Answer (score 2):

It is **not** true in general, note that for every complex number $e^z = \cos(z) + i \sin(z)$ (Euler's formula). We have
$$\left| \cot (\pi z) +  i \right| = \left| \frac{\cos( \pi z)}{\sin(\pi z)} + i \right| = \frac{\left| e^{i \pi z} \right| }{\left| \sin (\pi z) \right |} = \frac{1}{e^{\pi r}}\frac{1}{\left|\sin(\pi z) \right|}.$$
Also from Euler's formula,
$$\frac{1}{\left|\sin(\pi z)\right|} = \frac{2}{\left|e^{i \pi z} - e^{- i \pi z} \right|} = \frac{2\left| e^{\pi i z} \right|}{\left| e^{2i \pi z} - 1 \right|} = \frac{2}{e^{\pi r}}\frac{1}{\left|e^{2\pi i(x+ir)}- 1 \right|} = \frac{2}{e^{\pi r}}\frac{1}{\left|e^{-2\pi r}e^{2\pi i x} - 1 \right|}\\ = \frac{2}{e^{\pi r}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(e^{-2\pi r}\cos(2\pi x)-1)^2+(\sin(2\pi x))^2}}.$$
When $x$ is half of an odd integer, the denominator of the last expression is precisely $(1+e^{-2\pi r})$ so finally we still have
$$\left| \cot(\pi z) + i \right| = \frac{2}{1 + e^{2\pi r}}$$

Comment: My bad, I should have write x is half of odd integer I thought it is irrelevant

Comment: @Ali the important thing is the inequality is true regardless of condition on $x$.

Comment: Yes, I know. Thanks :) +1

Comment: @Ali, sorry, I went too fast, $x$ should be half of an odd.